# Selenium 'Unable to locate element'

Tags: java, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-ide

I know that there are a few questions similar to these one. I think I've gone through them, but I can not find how to resolve my problem.

The problem is as follows. I'm trying to use the Selenium driver to click on the icon/button on the 'https:/unsplash.com/' website that changes the display from single grid to multi grid.

The HTML tag for the icon is as follows:

```
<svg class="N1Ri-" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 32 32" 
    width="32" height="32" aria-labelledby="icon-title-635 
    icon-desc-636" aria-hidden="false" data-reactid=".pm6nw1xm9s.4.0.0.3.0.0.0.0.1.0">
<path d="M0 2v10c0 1.106 0.896 2 2 
    2h10c1.104 0 2-0.894 2-2v-10c0-1.106-0.896-2-2-2h-10c-1.104 0-2 
    0.894-2 2zM2 18c-1.104 0-2 0.894-2 2v10c0 1.106 
    0.896 2 2 2h10c1.104 0 2-0.894 2-2v-10c0-1.106-0.896-2-2-2h-10zM20 18c-1.106 0-2 
    0.894-2 2v10c0 1.106 0.894 2 2 2h10c1.106 0 2-0.894 2-2v-10c0-1.106-0.
    894-2-2-2h-10zM20 0c-1.106 0-2 0.894-2 2v10c0 1.106 
    0.894 2 2 2h10c1.106 0 2-0.894 2-2v-10c0-1.106-0.894-2-2-2h-10z" 
    data-reactid=".pm6nw1xm9s.4.0.0.3.0.0.0.0.1.0.1">
</path>
</svg>
```

The java code that I have is as follows:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","/home/ xxxx /Documents/Selenium/geckodriver");
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get("https:/unsplash.com/");

    //I've tried all of the following independently with the same result: 'Unable to locate element'
    driver.findElement(By.className("N1Ri")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.className("N1Ri-")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.className("svg.Hd1sr")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@class,'N1Ri')]")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='svg.Hd1sr']")).click();
}
```

As you will see in the code, I tried a range of options (I've tried many other combinations) but always with the same result: Unable to locate element

I tried also Senenium IDE and when clinking on the icon/button, the source showed: LOCATOR DETECTION FAILED

I'm guessing that there is something on the HTML code that prevents to easily  scraping the page.

My questions is twofold:
- What is the code to that I have to use in this case?
- (most importantly) How can I find the code to use in cases like this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this xpath

```
("//a[contains(@href,'multi')]/*[@class='Hd1sr']")
```

With the svg tag xpath is failing.

Or css

```
"a[href*='multi']>svg[class='Hd1sr']"
```

Comment: Thanks Grasshopper, with the xpath worked perfectly. With the css I've got again the same 'Unable to locate element' error. But how did you figure out the code? why do you need to use @href,'multi', for example? I can not figure out the syntaxis to use. Is there any code of reference to help on this?

Comment: @Selrac You can get plenty of resources on google and youtube for xpath and css locators for selenium. It is pretty easy to pickup. Else you can install firebug on firefox and it will automatically give you the locators. But you might need to modify them to be perfect.

Comment: I'll keep trying. Practice makes perfect. But I tried now and it didn't work. Inspecting the html code I noticed that it has changed and now to make it work I have to use: driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href,'multi')]/*[@class='N1Ri-']")).click();    Strange that now I'm seeing N1Ri- and 8 hours earlier I was seeing Hd1sr.

Comment: By.xpath("//a[contains(@href,'multi')]/*[‌​@class='N1Ri-' or @class='Hd1sr']") or try without the second part By.xpath("//a[contains(@href,'multi')]")

Comment: It worked with By.xpath("//a[contains(@href,'multi')]") . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("svg.N1Ri-")).click();
```

For some reason the xpath equivalent to this wouldn't work, I'm afraid I have no idea why.

Comment: Thanks Jsmith. Even though the code didn't cause the error, it didn't really actioned the click command